# MarkupExtension class in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps

I'm converting a WPF application to a Metro application. Some classes which are supported in WPF are not supported in Windows Store App. Like my code that is in WPF

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
[ContentProperty("Key")]
public class LocExtension : MarkupExtension
{
     // Code
}
```

How to do same thing in metro. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part of your code exactly is not compatabile?

Comment: This code is of WPF. Its not working in metro. So how i do same thing in metro ??

Comment: "Its not working" doesn't explain what the problem is.  What exactly is not working?  Is it not compiling?  Is it not doing what you think it should do?  Please provide details.